# Sorting is lost in asp.net on any gridview event

Tags: asp.net, gridview, datagridview

I have a website with a gridview where I want to be able to sort the columns. However when I click on edit or next page I lose my sort. How can I prevent this from happening. Is there any way that in my function Datatable() I could check to see if a sort happened.  I have found this link but I am unsure how to implement it with mine.

Here is how I populate my gridview.

```
    static DataTable Datatable()
    {
        ubicacion_componentes componenteLocations = new ubicacion_componentes();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("ubicacion_componente_id");
        dt.Columns.Add("armario");
        dt.Columns.Add("cajon");

        foreach (var cmp in componenteLocations.ubicaction_componentes)
        {
            var row = dt.NewRow();

            row["ubicacion_componente_id"] = cmp.ubicacion_componente_id;
            row["armario"] = cmp.armario;
            row["cajon"] = cmp.cajon;

            dt.Rows.Add(row);
        }
        return dt;
    }

    protected void BindGridList(string sortExp, string sortDir)
    {
        DataTable dt = Datatable();

        DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
        dv = dt.DefaultView;

        if (sortExp != string.Empty)
        {
            dv.Sort = string.Format("{0} {1}", sortExp, sortDir);
        }
        gvLocation.DataSource = dv;
        gvLocation.DataBind();

        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            gvLocation.DataSource = dt;
            gvLocation.DataBind();
        }
        else
        {
            dt.Rows.Add(dt.NewRow());
            gvLocation.DataSource = dt;
            gvLocation.DataBind();
            gvLocation.Rows[0].Cells.Clear();
            gvLocation.Rows[0].Cells.Add(new TableCell());
            gvLocation.Rows[0].Cells[0].ColumnSpan = dt.Columns.Count;
            gvLocation.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text = "datos no encontrados";
            gvLocation.Rows[0].Cells[0].HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
        }
    }
```

Here is how I sort in my datatable.

```
    public string sortOrder
    {
        get
        {
            if (ViewState["sortOrder"].ToString() == "desc")
            {
                ViewState["sortOrder"] = "asc";
            }
            else
            {
                ViewState["sortOrder"] = "desc";
            }

            return ViewState["sortOrder"].ToString();
        }
        set
        {
            ViewState["sortOrder"] = value;
        }
    }

    protected void gvLocation_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
    {
        BindGridList(e.SortExpression, sortOrder);
    }
```

Any help would be very appreciated

Comment: In `BindGridList` method why are you setting `gvLocation.DataSource` twice? This line `gvLocation.DataSource = dt` will undo the sorting applied using Dataview

Comment: Thank you thank you Mohsin Mehmood